# How to avoid commandButton to render all components in form submit?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, form-submit

i am working on JSF `primefaces`, in that i have a problem with submitting the form

**Problem Description :**

I am using primefaces tapView panel , in that every tap i have one set of input field with submitButton, Where i set all field are mandatory, if i am enter value one tap(tap1) field and give submit means the action is not getting triggered , the reason is because i set the other tap(tap2) **field are mandatory**, so the form is not getting submit .

**My JSF code :**

```
<h:form>
<p:tabView  >
<p:tab id="tap1" title="Tap1">

    <h:panelGrid>
        <h:panelGroup id="ip_leave">
    <h:outputText value="From"  styleClass="op1" style="margin-right:10px;" />
    <p:calendar pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" effect="drop" value="#{leavehistory.leaveFrom}" required="true" size="10"/>
    <h:outputText value="To"  styleClass="op1" style="margin-left:40px;margin-right:10px;"/>
    <p:calendar pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" effect="drop" value="#{leavehistory.leaveTo}" required="true" size="10"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Get"  actionListener="#{leavehistory.submitLeaveHistory}" update="tap1" style="margin-left:40px;" />
    </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:tab>
<p:tab id="tap2" title="Tap2">
    <h:panelGrid id="ip_reject">
            <h:panelGroup >
            <h:outputText value="From"  styleClass="op1" style="margin-right:10px;" />
            <p:calendar pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" effect="drop" value="#{leavehistory.rDateFrom}" required="true" size="10"/>
            <h:outputText value="To"  styleClass="op1" style="margin-left:40px;margin-right:10px;"/>
            <p:calendar pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" effect="drop" value="#{leavehistory.rDateTo}" required="true" size="10"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Get"  actionListener="#{leavehistory.submitRejectedLeaveHistory}" update="tap2" style="margin-left:40px;" />
            </h:panelGroup>
            </h:panelGrid>
</p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

*My question is how to partially submit fields in one tap alone ?*

---

**Updated :**

Finally worked with adding `process` attribute in commandButton

`<p:commandButton value="Get"  actionListener="#{leavehistory.submitLeaveHistory}" update="tap1" style="margin-left:40px;" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 'process' attribute on p:commandButton to name those components or their parent naming container that you want to have processed. Additionally you probably want to set the attribute 'partialSubmit' to true as well. This will stop PF from sending those fields to the server that won't be processed anyway.

Comment: can you plot with one example for how to use `process` attribute

Comment: Uhm, do you mean whether I can give you an example? I didn't intend to plot anything, especially not together with "some example" ;)